# Does implementation of epoll have any rfc?

Tags: linux, rfc, epoll

Many network protocols have their own rfc(request for comment),

like this one for http/1.1:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.1/rfc2616.pdf

does `epoll` have its own rfc online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`epoll` is a set of functions, not a network protocol. The `epoll(7)` man page is probably the clearest source of information about their usage.

Comment: No, but your comparison of epoll to a network protocol is a logical fallacy.